# Running apache on docker with Dockerfile in windows boot2docker

Tags: apache, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I created the Dockerfile below and I tried to build the docker file but it's stop in Step 7 with below issue.

```
FROM fedora:20


RUN yum -y update; yum clean all


RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/httpd
RUN mkdir -p /bin/httpd-run
# Create Apache test page
RUN echo "Apache set up successfully." > /var/www/html/index.html

# Copy apache run script
ADD httpd-run /bin/httpd-run

# Done
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/httpd-run"]
```

```
docker@boot2docker:~/c$ docker build --rm -t neroinc/frdora-apache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM fedora:20
 ---> 6cece30db4f9
Step 1 : RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31c60bf0f22d
Step 2 : RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6efbe9b41918
Step 3 : RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> acd918c77d60
Step 4 : RUN mkdir -p /var/log/httpd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9e069fbfb24
Step 5 : RUN mkdir -p /bin/httpd-run
 ---> Running in 71735c1e8b7e
 ---> c6dab827ab33
Removing intermediate container 71735c1e8b7e
Step 6 : RUN echo "Apache set up successfully." > /var/www/html/index.html
 ---> Running in 8f6f38bdd492
 ---> c4f21e9f64b7
Removing intermediate container 8f6f38bdd492
Step 7 : ADD httpd-run /bin/httpd-run
INFO[0001] httpd-run: no such file or directory

docker@boot2docker:~/c$
```

If anyone can help me I'm new to write code. Here I want add any folder in boot2docker vm
I want write Dockerfile for Apache.

Comment: your line beginning with `ADD` should copy a file that is not found. Do you have a file httpd-run in your directory ?

Comment: No!.. please tell me how to create httpd-run file in my directory

Comment: I created directory with httpd-run then it will working :-) Thanks